# How to send CTRL+C without press?

Tags: bash

I have a script e. g. a.sh, which calls script b.sh.

After execution, I want that the b.sh will be interrupt after 5 secs and then it will be executed again.

Any ideas, how I can run it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the calling in a loop and use `timeout` to kill the second script after a certain amount of time, like say

```
while true; do
    timeout 5s b.sh
done
```

unless you don't really want it looping endlessly, if you just want it to timeout then execute once more:

```
timeout 5s b.sh
b.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while true; do timeout 5 /path/to/b.sh; done
```

Answer (score 1):

CTRL+C is sending the `SIGINT` command. By default the `timeout` is sending the `SIGTERM` signal, thus making the accepted solution inaccurate. If you really want to send the `SIGINT` you can do it by passing:

```
timeout -s SIGINT 5 b.sh
```

You can also pass different signals to the `timeout` command. You can see a list of all of them by executing `kill -l`.

And you can do the loop with `while` as suggested in the other comments.

Answer (score 0):

`a` can kill `b` with `-INT`. That pretty much has the effect of `Ctrl-C`:

```
a_sh()
{
    b_sh & 
    pid=$!
    while :; do 
        sleep 5
        kill -INT $pid
    done
}
b_sh()
{
    trap 'echo ouch' SIGINT #if this isn't here, b will die after 5 seconds instead of just saying 'ouch' 
    i=0;
    while :; do
        echo loop $i
        sleep 1;
        i=$((i+1))
    done
}

a_sh
```